# Account was hacked and leveled.. What do I do now?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I've never touched MoP but I was going to give it a whirl a couple days ago when I noticed I was banned. Went thru the process of getting it fixed and now I'm level 88 with (only?) 8k gold and old gear still.

I don't know if I can tank (warrior): I still have ZA/ZG 'epics' and my non-tank gear is still ruthless stuff.

I was, for some reason, in a WoTLK map when I logged in so I don't know where to go. Where should I level at 88 and is the tank gear I have, gold I have decent to run thru the new dungeons?

I'd like to not make anyone mad, ha.

Thanks!

Comment: I have heard of people's account being hacked and their gold and stuff being stolen (haven't happened in a long while though), but never heard of an account being hacked for playing (leveling and stuff). No offence, but this made me giggle. Good to know the world still has weird people out there somewhere :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your gear is okay to head to the correct zone in Pandaria for a level 88. I'd recommend that to be Kun-lai Summit or Towlong Steppes. You'll replace the gear pretty fast with quest greens, but it won't stop you levelling in the mean time. Regarding 8k gold, it isn't a great deal, but it will buy you the necessities and then more. You'll be fine tanking the current instances.

In order to get back to Pandaria, you need to head to either Stormwind or Orgrimmar (depending on your faction). There you will be able to take a portal to Jade Forest in Pandaria.

I suspect the hacker didn't level using quests, but just by farming mobs. Probably a bot doing this. You might not have any flight paths to the desired zones, so you might have to spend some time trekking across Pandaria. It shouldn't take too long. And quests should be available when you get there. Hope that helps.

Comment: As for the gold, it really depends on the server too. I was on a low population server, and was cheap about buying my own gems/enchants/glyphs (guild would provide). So 8K gold could be a lot, it was for me at one time (until I stacked for the Sandstone Drake).